# In Outlook, how to close message in separate window?

Tags: outlook-addin, office-js

I need a function or API call where I can close the separate window of any selected email.

When you double click a message, it opens the message in a separate window, aye? Now how can I close it programmatically? Couldn't find anything in various documentations.

Thanks for any hints!

Answer (score 0):

Outlook Web Add-ins run within the context of the message, either within the primary client or in a separate window.

There is no method of closing the host window from the web add-in.